# Difference between array in row and columns

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm trying to move the content of column B3:B11 (range) to a column determined by the number of day in month at cell C3 (day). For each day in month (reeksorg) cell D2 contains: 1, E2: 2, F2: 3; up-to 31.

```
function Move() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // get present workbook
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //get active sheet
var range = ss.getRange('B3:B11').getValues(); //assign the range you want 
// to copy

var day = ss.getRange('C3').getValues();  // day from date(C1)

Logger.log(day);             // this is correct in Log
Logger.log(range);           // idem
Logger.log(range.length);    // idem

var reeksorg = ss.getRange('D2:H2').getValues(); // "reeksorg" are day-
// numbers within month

Logger.log(reeksorg);         // returns "range", should be [[1.0],[2.0]] 
//  etc.
Logger.log(reeksorg.length);  // returns [1.0],  should be [5.0]  
}
```

Although the statements to create both ranges are similar the outcome differs.

See Log-output:

> [17-08-18 16:04:21:095 CEST] [[3.0]]
>
> [17-08-18 16:04:21:095 CEST] [[5.0], [6.0], [7.0], [8.0], [9.0], [10.0], 
>      [11.0], [12.0], [13.0]]
>
> [17-08-18 16:04:21:096 CEST] 9.0
>
> [17-08-18 16:04:21:198 CEST] [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]]
>
> [17-08-18 16:04:21:198 CEST] 1.0

My goal is to copy "range" to the appropriate row/column (D3:H11) using a for loop.
Please help, i've limited programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function Move() 
{
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss=sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var srcrange=ss.getRange('B3:B11');
  var day=ss.getRange('C3').getValue();// day from date(C1)
  var desrange=ss.getRange(3,day,10,1);
  srcrange.copyTo(desRange);
}
```